# What is $\sum_{i=1}^{r} (i^{-1/3})$?.

Tags: harmonic-numbers

What is $\sum_{i=1}^{r} (i^{-1/3})$?. 
Is there any general formula for $\sum_{i=1}^{r} (i^{-1/n})$ for any integer $n$?

Comment: Using the [Riemann zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Hurwitz zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) functions, $$\sum_{k=1}^rk^{p}=\zeta(p)-\zeta(p,r+1)$$ for any complex $p$.  Thought probably not what you were looking for I assume?

Comment: The sum is $$r^{1-1/n}\frac1r\sum_{i=1}^r\left(\frac{i}r\right)^{-1/n}\sim r^{1-1/n}\int_0^1x^{-1/n}dx=\frac{n}{n-1}r^{(n-1)/n}$$ when $r\to\infty$ for $n>1$ fixed.

Comment: @Did Haha, that's not closed form, but good approximation.

Comment: Yes, there exists no closed form.